# Connect MySQL with Python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a library to connect to MySQL with Python 3.6. All libraries I found did only work with older versions of Python. Sadly I can't change to an older Python version because i need some functions, which are introduced in Python 3.6.

I am programming on a raspberry pi3, but I don't think this should change anything.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what was introduced in Python 3.6 that you need?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: The question title of the OP seems clear to me. He is looking for a way to connect python 3.6 to the MySQL client when the installer only points to 3.4. This question is a good one and I also looking for this answer.

Comment: currently up for 10 months, 8 upvotes, 25,347 views...  obviously a popular question with a clear problem and answer...  closed as off topic...    the poster did not ask which was best--only asked for possibilities to solve a well described problem...  some people with too many points need to get their heads out of there, it's an exit only orifice

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/    Development releases -> download for 3.6

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`mysqlclient` supports python3.6 officially.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

Comment: I installed mysqlclient with no errors, but I didn't manage to import it in my python script. I tried everything i found on the internet like import myslqclient, mysql, _mysql, mysqldb, ... but nothing worked out fine...

Comment: I peronally suggest you to use cursor: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MySQLdb.html#module-MySQLdb.cursors

Comment: I followed the Readme (https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/README.md) from their Github

Comment: import _mysql is working with Python 2.7.9, but i need python 3.6

Comment: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#some-examples

Comment: Python3.6: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
It's working with Python 2.7...

Comment: did you install with pip3?

Comment: I did "sudo pip3 mysqlclient". For mysqldb it's not working with pip3

Comment: does pip3 not working with normal user(not root?)

Comment: pip3 install mysqldb (without sudo) isn't working aswell: 
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement MySQLdb

Comment: I reinstalled mysqlclient manual with the source package and not with pip and now it's working.

Comment: Does the mysqlclient also support mariaDB?

Comment: @ClintStreet Sure