# Installing MySqlDB on Python 3.6

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am unable to resolve this issue for a day now. when i try to execute my django project, pycharm throws the error **"No module named 'MySQLdb'"**. From reference to similar questions on SO. I did try to install packages through file settings, that raises another error

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb"
```

My project requires python 3.6 and the project doesn't seem to be working without MysqlDB. I did try to install mysqlAlchemy and mysqlconnector but it is of no use. Can some one point out how to resolve this ?

I am on mac and there is no issue if i try to run the project from terminal.

EDIT : I did try to install mysql from the pycharm package manager. But it throws another error `No module named 'ConfigParser'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip) It lists the mac instructions there...

Comment: @metatoaster i am not able to install mysql through package manager of pycharm since it throws the error no module found 'configparser'

Comment: [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: For the edit, it's a duplicate of [Connect MySQL with Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515854/connect-mysql-with-python-3-6)

Answer (score 5):

It's a common problem in python3.5.3, you may need to `pip install pymysql` and add the following code to `__init__.py` at the same directory as `wsgi.py`. Wish you good luck!

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: I have no idea what "you may need to pip install pymysql and add the following code to __init__.py at the same directory as wsgi.py" means but I added import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb() to the top of my .py script and it worked.