# MySQLdb - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm failing at importing MySQLdb: `import MySQLdb` results in:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

I installed the following:

1. `pip install mysql-python`
2. `pip install mysqlclient`
3. `apt-get install python3-dev python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`
4. `apt-get install python-mysqldb` (which according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873259/3512538) should suffice)

Here is my `pip freeze | grep -i sql`:

- `mysqlclient==1.3.13`
- `MySQL-python==1.2.5`

I'm using Python 3.6 with PyCharm Community Edition on a virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04

What is missing here in order to use this? (also, is there another recommended module for Python API into mysql?)

---

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475877/3512538) states there is no MySQLdb for Python3.X, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515924/3512538) (and [this](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)) show it is alive and kicking, I think...

Comment: You should use pip3 instead of pip

Comment: @Mufeed Thanks! that was it (In the meantime I switched to Python 2 and it worked there). Would you like to answer so I could accept?

Comment: I added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `pip3` instead of `pip`, since you are using Python 3.6.
Use pip for Python2.x 
So your command should be like

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: actually `pip3 install mysql-python` gave an error. The `pip3 install mysqlclient` worked and solved the issue

Comment: Okay. I added it as an example.

Comment: it is better to use `python3 -m pip install ...` i.e. explicitly specify which Python version to use

Comment: I believe they both are equivalent.